# Trying to populate details section when clicking on Node of a GWT CellTree

Tags: java, gwt

Been a user of stackoverflow for the last 2 years but this is my first post.   I have built a CellTree that is populated from a db (RPC call) where each level of the tree is a different object (class).  Host -> Group -> Object -> Element.  What I am trying to do is populate a "details" section on my form that allows the user to edit the details of the node clicked, ultimately displaying the attributes of the class.  In the getNodeInfo section of my TreeViewModel I created an AbstractCell for each class / object.  I then added a click handler to each cell to capture the value / object the user clicks on.  I am able to see the correct value where I have the "System.out.println" line of code.  Where I'm stuck is being able to pass that object back to the form.

Here's my code, let me know if you need more info ... I blocked out the code for 3 of the levels as its basically the same except for a different class.

```java
public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(final T value) {
  // build root host nodes
  if (value == null) {
    final ListDataProvider<Host> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Host>();
    AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Host>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Host>>() {
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      String details = caught.getMessage();
      System.out.println ("Error:  " + details);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Host> result) {
      // Add the data to the data provider, which automatically pushes it to the widget.
      final List<Host> hostList = dataProvider.getList();
      for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        Host host = new Host();
        host.setHost_id(result.get(i).getHost_id());
        host.setHost(result.get(i).getHost());
        hostList.add(host);
      }  
    }
  };  
  termSvc.getHosts(callback);
  Cell<Host> cell = new AbstractCell<Host>() {
    public void render(Context context, Host value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
      if (value != null) {
        sb.appendEscaped(value.getHost());
      }
    }
  };
  selectionModelHost.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Host selected = ((SingleSelectionModel<Host>) selectionModelHost).getSelectedObject();
      System.out.println ("Value: " + selected.getHost());
    }
  });
  return new DefaultNodeInfo<Host>(dataProvider, cell, selectionModelHost, null);
  }
  // if its a host then go get the objects
  else if (value instanceof Host) {
    // ....................
  }
  // if its a Group then go get the objects
  else if (value instanceof Group) {
    // ....................
  }
  // if its an object, go get the elements
  else if (value instanceof DGObject) {
    // ....................
  }
  return null;
}
```

I saw this one which helped:  [GWT CellTree with an optional pop-up menu triggered on click of a TreeNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843405/gwt-celltree-with-an-optional-pop-up-menu-triggered-on-click-of-a-treenode)   And I based a lot of my code on the GWT examples. I searched for an answer already so hopefully I'm headed in the right direction and not asking something that has already been answered.  Thanks

------------- added after Andrea's answer:

Here is the form that calls the celltree.  Currently I only have a label and the celltree on the form as I am trying to determine on the form what node the user is clicking.   I'm populating the tree successfully (and will look into cleaning it up a bit) but struggling to know what the object (node) selected in the tree is to populate the label.

```java
public class TabAssetPanel extends Composite {

  interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, TabAssetPanel> {
    Widget createAndBindUi(TabAssetPanel tabAssetPanel);
  }

  private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

  @UiField
  CellTree assetCellTree;
  @UiField
  Label assetSelected;

  public TabAssetPanel () {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    final SingleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<String>();
    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
      public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        String selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        assetSelected.setText(selected);
      }
    }); 

    AssetTreeViewModel model = new AssetTreeViewModel(selectionModel);
    CellTree assetCellTree = new CellTree(model, "root");
    assetCellTree.setVisible(true);
  }

  @UiFactory
  CellTree makeCellTree() { 

    final SingleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<String>();
    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
      public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        String selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        assetSelected.setText(selected);
      }
    }); 

    AssetTreeViewModel model = new AssetTreeViewModel(selectionModel);
    return new CellTree(model, null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok to me. Maybe there is too much code within the `getNodeInfo()` method, so try to refactor a bit, extracting out `AsyncCallback`s and `DataProvider`s.

But anyway, when you have your selected object in hand, to populate your form (that I'm assuming is somewhere else), I'd create a callback to call within your `SelectionModel`s or find a way to register the selection handler in a place you can access your form elements, or use an app-wide event bus on which publish events other part of the app (say, the view that hold your form) are listening to.

It totally depends on how your application is structured, there is no *right* solution. If you use Activities & Places framework, the event bus is, IMHO, a no brainer solution.

Also, you can even shift you logic a bit in a way your tree simply contains identifiers for your backed objects, then you can publish a place change (via `Places` or `History`) with such ids and the other parts of the app will react on such change by querying the server for the right object (to put it simply: the tree contains a visual representation of the node, but the call for the real object is done somewhere else, where you actually need it).

Again, just guessing.

Hope that helps, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I'll add some code showing the form that calls the model and expand the question a little.  Appreciate the advice regarding the "bulk" code and the Activities & Places framework.  I'll look into both of those as well.  Thanks!